# How to create simple set in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list, collections, set, hashtable

What I mean by simple set is set in a sense of simple collections of stuffs

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)

So not set in a sense of setting some variable into something.

I can use list(of string). However, say I don't care about order. I care that every item is there exactly once. Well, list is not appropriate right? Unless we have a different code.

I look for "set" in vb.net but I got results for different meaning of set.

as far as I know, hashtable(of string) is not available.

What would be the appropriate container?

The collection should only check whether an object exist or not in the set. That's it. O(1) for both operation

Answer (score 3):

You want the [`HashSet(Of T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0) class. It works basically the same way as the `Keys` of a `Dictionary`, where items are first compared by the result of their `GetHashCode` methods and, if those are the same, their `Equals` method.

It's worth noting that `HashSet(Of T)` implements `ICollection(Of T)`, and therefore `IEnumerable(Of T)`, but not `IList(Of T)`. That means that you can enumerate the collection using a `For Each` loop and you can get the `Count`, but items have no index.

As mentioned in the comment below, the `Add` method will return a `Boolean` to indicate whether the item was added or not, based on whether the item was already contained in the set (`False`) or not (`True`).

Comment: I forget. You see. I mean searching for set shows different things.